# Using common methods

Tags: sql, asp.net

> i'm using the following method for all data inserting and updating
>   processes in my application.i just need to pass array of sql quires to
>   the method.are there any disadvantages of using one common method.does
>   it cause any performance reduction in the application

```
 public int ExecuteCommand(string[] sqls)
        {
            numberOfRecordsAffected = 0;

            IngresConnection ingresConnection = new IngresConnection(ConnStr);
            IngresTransaction ingresTransaction = null;
            try
            {
                ingresConnection.Open();

                ingresTransaction = ingresConnection.BeginTransaction();

                foreach (string sql in sqls)
                {
                    IngresCommand ingresCommand = new IngresCommand(sql, ingresConnection, ingresTransaction);
                    ingresCommand.CommandTimeout = 0;
                    numberOfRecordsAffected += ingresCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }

                ingresTransaction.Commit();

            }
            catch
            {
                if (ingresTransaction != null)
                    ingresTransaction.Rollback();
                ingresConnection.Close();
                throw;
            }
            finally
            {
                if (ingresConnection != null)
                    ingresConnection.Close();
            }

            return numberOfRecordsAffected;
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this [opinionated article](http://www.knowdotnet.com/articles/dynamisql.html) about dynamic sql. You ask specifically about performance which indeed is hurt a lot because your queries can't be cached by the database and each of them need to be parsed. The real worry should be about security though. It's so easy to do it wrong/incomplete at one point or the other and it's even harder to test if it has been messed up somewhere or not.